# Vuetify v-row background image height

Tags: css, vuetify.js, background-image

I am trying to put a background image in a v-row such that the width fills the screen and the height of the v-row adjusts automatically.

```
<v-row class="bg" align="center" justify="center">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
      Date picker 1
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" background="white">
      Date picker 2
    </v-col>
</v-row>

.bg {
  background: url("../assets/hills.jpg") no-repeat center center;
 }
```

Without any height styles I get #1. I would like the effect shown in #2:

[image]

So how can I set the height of the v-row to fit the height of the image? I realise

```
height: 100%
```

won't increase the height of the containing v-row - the style being applied to the v-row not the image. This

```
height: 100vh;
```

works to an extent, but the height reflects the height of the viewport, not the background image and is therefore too large. A fixed height will work

```
height: 600px;
```

but will need to be adjusted for screen size.

Is there an solution?

Comment: Could you describe what you want the effect to be for example if the device is in portrait mode, or more generally, if the viewport's aspect ratio is very different from the image's?

Comment: Simply for the width to be 100% of the window (either rotation) and the height to be adjusted automatically according to the image width:height ratio. After further reading I suspect it can only be done using js calcualtions and then adding the style to the v-row.

Comment: Or maybe putting in an img element rather than trying to use a background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an image you could use:

```
position: absolute;
object-fit: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Then this will grow to the size of the content (providing the parent is `position: relative;` whilst remaining proportional. If you adjust the padding on the content with media queries or similar you should be able to get the effect you are looking for.